# Angular 2 - How to get language culture name (en-US) from route?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am not able to find the lang-culture (e.g en-US/he-IL etc) from the URL as parameters. In my app.router.ts

```
export const localeRouter: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'he-IL',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    { path: 'he-IL', children: ... },
    { path: 'en-US', children: ... }
];
export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(localeRouter);
```

My generated URLs look like this

> www.domain.com/he-IL/auctions/1587(For Hebrew)
>
> www.domain.com/en-US/auctions/1587(For English)

I need to get this part (lang-culture e.g en-US) from URL to load the resources for that culture on ASP.NET MVC side.

I am trying to find it from `ActivatedRoute` instance on my component but having some issues.

One way I found out is:

```
this.route.parent.parent.snapshot.url
```

but the problem with this is the sequence of `.parent` would be different in each component based on the route, I want a generic solution that would work on all components. Any suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't the lang-culture be an URL param (i.e. `path: ":lang/foo"`) so you can retrieve it from `route.snapshot.params.lang`? (side note: there's also `this.route.pathFromRoot`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to get the first path slice on your URL:

```
getLanguageFromLocation(): string {
    const pathSlices = location.pathname.split('/');

    if (pathSlices.length > 1)
        return pathSlices[1];

    if (pathSlices.length)
        return pathSlices[0];
}
```

Comment: Meanwhile, feel free to have a look at [@nglibs/i18n-router](https://github.com/nglibs/i18n-router), demonstrating the implementation of route internationalization on the client side.